# A group that is its own classfying space

Tags: group-theory, homotopy-theory, classifying-spaces

Does there exist $n \in \mathbb N $ and a non-trivial topological Group $G$, such that  $G = K (G,n)$ ? Apart from knowing that such $G$ cannot be discrete, I have absolutely no idea how to tackle this Problem. Any help is appreciated.